EasyScintilla - after installing from NuGet, there are no components that can be added to the toolbox for EasyScintilla.DLL
I would like to add the EasyScintilla to a VB.NET project. I install EasyScintilla to my project from NuGet. As mentioned in https://github.com/adam8797/EasyScintilla, the newly added control is not added to the toolbox.
When I right-click my Toolbox, select Choose Items, browse to my project directory, and select EasyScintilla.DLL, I get the following error:
There are no components in EasyScintilla.DLL that can be placed on the toolbox
I tried the drag-and-drop solution in There are no components in DLL that can be placed on toolbox but the dll cannot be dropped at all onto any window in Visual Studio 2017.
Is there any possible way to add EasyScintilla to a .NET project?
